# nswag net 6 auto generated c# client

Tags: openapi, openapi-generator, nswag, nswagstudio

I have an .net 6 api that already uses swagger to generate the swagger UI. I am attempting to create a C# client that lives in a class library. The structure will look something like this.

- Application.API - the project with the api
- Application.API.Http - the class library that will contain the c# client

I attempted to use nswag studio to generate a nswag.json file. I then used the nswag.msbuild package to generate the c# client on build. This works, exept for the following issue... The nswag.json contains the definition for the API, the result is that the c# client does not contain changes to the API.

I have seen some examples of nswag.json that do not explicitly include the definition, however I have not gotten any to work.

How would I configure the API to generate the c# client based on the current code of the API, not the definition generated in nswag studio?